# Ext.Net X.GetCmp method not working with FileUploadField

Tags: vb.net, ext.net

This is my first question. I am in stack overflow almost every day, but this is the first time I can't find the answer by myself and have to post it here.

I am creating pages with `Ext.Net` dynamically (in VB.net if it matters), based on a XML configuration, with all kind of controls and any number of them. So, for each field in the XML, I create the control and assign an ID to it (the ID is from the XML). I have a "submit" button that, when clicked, parse the XML again, get the ID of each field, and gets the control for this ID with `Ext.Net.X.GetCmp`. Then, once I have the control, I get the value and do some stuff with it. Everything works like a charm except for the control type `FileUploadField`. According to [this](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?16885-how-to-get-the-FileUploadField-fullpath-in-code-behind-use-it-s-I), for some reason, `GetCmp` doesn't work with `FileUploadField`.

So, my question is: Is there some way to get a `FileUploadField` control based on it's ID? And, just to know, why `GetCmp` doesn't work with this kind of control?

Thank you very much in advance, and sorry for my bad english.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I have updated my Ext.Net to the latest version (2.2). Everything now looks strange, but it doesn't matter, if it works. Besides the appearance, I don't see any change in the behavior. GetCmp is still giving me the same. By the way, X.GetCmp(Of Ext.Net.FileUploadField)(ControlID) gives me a FileUploadField, not null, even if I don't create the control. The only thing, is that hasFile=false always, and the filebytes are empty.

**EDIT 2:**

I have run your example code and it works like a charm. I start thinking that the "isUpload" is the key.  I Have been googling all the day trying to see where and why do I have to write this {isUpload=true}, but I didn't see anything useful. Can you explain it to me a little bit? Is only for DirectMethods? Is mandatory? Thanks a lot!

**EDIT 3:**

I feel sooooo stupid now. It works. Just added a simple isUpload:true in the DirectMethod call in a javascript. So many days to solve this stupid thing. For the next guy: check your isUpload ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > So, my question is: Is there some way to get a FileUploadField control based on it's ID?

Only recreating that control. You render a control during one AJAX request (DirectEvent/DirectMethod) and it doesn't persist during another AJAX request unless you recreate it manually. It behaves the same as standard ASP.NET controls.

Controls can be recreated in Page_Init and must be recreated with the same IDs. In this case, a control's LoadPostData should extract a correct value from a POST collection. [Here is a related discussion](http://forums.asp.net/t/1186195.aspx).

> > And, just to know, why GetCmp doesn't work with this kind of control?

It doesn't work in Ext.NET v1, but works in Ext.NET v2. Here is a sample below.

Though, it just extracts a file from the POST. X.GetCmp<>() returns a proxy control, it is not a real control. It is just a convenient way to extract POST values of dynamically rendered controls and, also, updates those controls on client (changing its properties and calling its methods).

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void RenderFileUploadField(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        FileUploadField fileUploadField = new FileUploadField()
            {
                ID = "FileUploadField1",
                Width = 300,
                Listeners =
                {
                    Change =
                    {
                        Handler = @"App.direct.GetFileName(this.id, {
                                        isUpload : true
                                    });"
                    }
                }
            };
        this.Form.Controls.Add(fileUploadField);
        fileUploadField.Render();
    }

    [DirectMethod]
    public void GetFileName(string id)
    {
        X.Msg.Alert("FileName", X.GetCmp<FileUploadField>("FileUploadField1").PostedFile.FileName).Show();
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET v2 Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />
        <ext:Button
            runat="server"
            Text="Create a FileUploadField"
            OnDirectClick="RenderFileUploadField" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why is there a need to use X.GetCmp, why not use client-sided App.{ID}?

Comment: First of all thank you very much for the help.
So, it is fixed in Ext.Net2. Great! I read the changelogs, but I didn't see anything about it.
About the solution you propose, maybe is because it's friday, or maybe because I am too new to all this things, but I don't understand. What do you mean with recreating that control? When and how do I recreate the control? And, if I recreate the control, even if I can look for the control by ID, I wouldn't get another control, without any file?
Sorry if my questions are too stupid :).

Comment: @Vogel612, you can use App.{ID} on client side, but not on server side.

Comment: @JoséRamón, regarding changelog. I think there was no commit specially for this issue. Probably, it has been fixed due to redesigning something. Regarding recreating controls. They can be recreated in Page_Init and must be recreated with the same IDs. In this case, a control's LoadPostData should extract a correct value from a POST collection. Here is a related [discussion](http://forums.asp.net/t/1186195.aspx). I updated the answer.

Comment: Ok Daniil, now I understand why do I have to recreate them in each callback. Now I create the controls in each call to Page_Load. I think this part was already working, because I could get all other components (except FileUploadField). I just checked that still can't get the control with GetCmp. Now, what do you mean with use LoadPostData to extract the value from a POST collection? Do you have any quick pseudo-code to explain what you mean? Thanks. I'm really stuck with this stupid problem...

Comment: Hi Danniil. I have updated the Ext.Net, but still doesn't work. Are you sure your GetCmp works always? Let say, triggered in a button click? I have updated my question.

Comment: Ok, is working. Thank you very much Daniil. Maybe your solutions didn't work directly, but indirectly. The solution was always there, in your example: isUpload=true. Thanks.

Comment: Nice. A "isUpload: true" setting for a DirectMethod and a IsUpload="true" one for a DirectEvent are required for an AJAX request which is supposed to download or upload a file. We might need to rename it to something like IsTransmitFile, because it is confusing a necessity to set up IsUpload="true" for downloading.

Answer (score 0):

you could use simple javascript:

```
var fileinput = document.getElementById("fileinput");
```

as javascript does only search the DOM you need to be careful. each Ext.Net component will get a bunch of wrappers and sub-components and "unnecessary" siblings/parents/children (for header, label, bottom- and topbar and so on..)

if you have given an ID to the control you should be able to fetch it via:

```
App.{control-id}
```

this will return the constructor. you should be able to fetch `FileBytes` from ExtJS anytime using the App namespace (see [BREAKING CHANGES](http://examples.ext.net/#/Getting_Started/Release_Documents/BREAKING_CHANGES/))

the finished get for the FileBytes would look like this:

```
App.{control-id}.FileBytes
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Vogel.

I don't use the solution provided by Daiil, because I don't want to do anything until the user press the "ok" button, not when the user upload a single file. Let's say I have a form with 2 upload fields and a text field. Then, if the user select 2 files, and press Ok, those files will be sent to another server. If he doesn't press the Ok, the process is cancelled, so the server doesn't change anything in its state.

Comment: Actually is a much more complex than a form with an Ok button, but I don't want to go into detail, because it's irrelevant I think. The thing is I want to react on an event not related to the fileuploadfield, so I need to get the control.FileBytes from outside. But I can't find the control, if you know what I mean.

Comment: About your solution, if I want to get the content of the file, I can't do just fileinput.FileBytes I suppose right?

Comment: @JoséRamón well this is for `<input type="file" name="file" id="fileinput"/>` and you can get its file by `document.getElementById("fileinput").files[0]` and send it as `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`. concerning the other stuff. can't you go `App.fileinput.FileBytes` ?